# Table stylish in last Google Chart version (v42)

Tags: css, google-visualization

With the last google chart version, v42 some of the stylish I have for table have changed. This is the actual code I have:

https://jsfiddle.net/Khrys/mLgn76fu/

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

  function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
    data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
      ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
      ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
      ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]
    ]);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    $(".google-visualization-table-table").find('*').each(function (i, e) {
    var classList = e.className ? e.className.split(/\s+/) : [];
        $.each(classList, function (index, item) {
            if (item.indexOf("google-visualization") === 0) {
                $(e).removeClass(item);
            }
        });
    });

    $(".google-visualization-table-table")
        .removeClass('google-visualization-table-table')
        .addClass('table table-striped table-condensed table-hover')
        .css("width", "85%");
    });

    table.draw(data);
  }
```

This isn't working anymore. This should read the classes from bootstrap and render the table with bootstrap classes for table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function applying the style is applying it to the parent div. I changed to add .find('table') to get to the table child.

https://jsfiddle.net/mLgn76fu/7/

```
        $(".google-visualization-table")
        .removeClass('google-visualization-table')
        .find('table')
        .addClass('table table-striped table-condensed table-hover')
        .css("width", "85%");
    });
```

[image]

That works as a quick solution. In fact, the real problem and a better solution would be to rewrite the class "killer" you have as that is not doing what you expect. That is why the class ends up as google-visualization-table and not with table-table on the end as you expected.

I would just kill all classes, like this:

```
    $(".google-visualization-table").find('*').each(function (i, e) {
        $(e).removeClass();
    });
```

And then add your bootstrap ones like in the fiddle or code above.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You did it!